# Ищу библиотеку

Tags: java, библиотеки

Есть ли в java библиотеке по парсингу сложных языковых конструкций. Пример какой нибудь ЯП, тот же JAVA. Например есть код:

```
public class Test()
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public void getX()
    {/* body */}
}
```

И в зависимости от шаблонов, заданных этой библиотеке получить в итоге массив с некоторой структурой. Пример:
    [{'isClassTmpl', 'public' 'class' 'Test', 'inside': { ... }, ...}]

Прекрасно было бы работать с шаблонами вида: [if] (*condition*) {*namespace*};

В целом задача стоит в том чтобы запарсить код по шаблонам и получить на выходе массив в котором бы указывались данные и по какому шаблону это данные были получены.

У гугла даже не знаю как такое спросить. Если кто то сможет подсказать библиотеку для другого ЯП, тоже буду благодарен, хоть код тогда посмотреть если open source.

Comment: думаю нету, так как по примеру - можно самому быстро сделать...

Comment: я сделал сам конечно. Но не быстро.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В старом добром С это решалось посредством YACC (Yet Another Compiler Compiler == Еще один компилятор компилятора). На роль YACC в Java лучше всего тянет [CUP](http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/) - естественно поддерживается задание грамматики вашего *языка*

Возьмите его, задайте вашу грамматику и сгенерируйте парсер и вперед

Comment: Может JavaCC? (Но я его не знаю и не видел).

Comment: Аналог YACC в GNU это bison. 

Но, IMHO это одно и то же для этой задачи, только идеи посмотреть. Реально перетянуть куски в java вряд ли получится.

Насколько помню, по описанию грамматики они генерят программу на Си.